# How to import parent object field in lightning record form of child custom object?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, relationships, fields, lightning-record-form

There is `Contact` object as parent object and I have created a custom object called `Vaccination_Information__c` which is a child of `Contact` object.

I want to include the contact name field from `Contact` object in `Vaccination_Information__c` object lightning record form that I have created using LWC. How should I import it in the JS file?

Below is the code line that I have written but shows error:

```javascript
import CONTACTNAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Vaccination_Information__c.Contact__c';
```

where `Contact__c` is the api name for the master detail relationship. and the error is:

> Invalid reference Vaccination_Information__c.Contact__c of type sobjectClass in file vaccineReg.js

Answer (score 0):

lightning-record-edit-form does not allow you to display the parent field directly.
In order to use them on child object lightning record form, You need to do something like this:-

- Use nested record edit form outer one for child and inner one for parent
- define a onload handler of the child and fetch the parent record id
- pass the fetched parent record id to parent record edit form to load parent record
- on click of submit, save both the form programmatically

  ```
   <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={objectApiName} record-id={recordId} onload={handleLoad}>
       <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"></lightning-input-field>
       <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId"></lightning-input-field>
       <!--Account field starts from here-->
       <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account" record-id={accId}>
           <lightning-input-field field-name="Type"></lightning-input-field>
       </lightning-record-edit-form>
       <!--submit button to save both account and contact-->
       <div class="slds-var-m-top_medium">
           <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={handleSubmit}>
           </lightning-button>
       </div>
   </lightning-record-edit-form>
  ```

JS File:-

```
    accId;
    // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;

    handleLoad(event) {
        var record = event.detail.records;
        var fields = record[this.recordId].fields;
        this.accId = fields.AccountId.value;
    }

    handleSubmit() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-record-edit-form').forEach(element => {
            element.submit();
        });
    }
```

When i added the component on child record page, it comes with both parent and child record fields
[image]